# Adding an entity reference field to entity

Tags: 7, entities

I'm looking for a way to add an EntityReference field to an Entity, but haven't found an answer to this.  Is it possible?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the admin section for your entity / entity types, and add fields with the Manage Fields tab (just like you would for content types).

Comment: Man, I was looking for that menu, but after reading your answer, I double checked and field_ui wasn't enabled.  After turning that on, that menu option was available.  Thanks, for the kick in the right direction.

Comment: It happens, heh